# All POST tests failing in Postman collection run

Tags: java, websphere, postman, java-ee-6, postman-collection-runner

I have been tasked with determining why certain tests are failing in Postman's collection runner. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969832/404-error-when-post-in-postman) helpful but it does not address the scope of my issue.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357786/how-do-i-fail-a-test-if-postman-response-status-code-is-500-server-error) suggests I could be sending the request with invalid JSON, but I did not write these tests, so I am unsure of how to check that.

**My collection runs 423 GET/POST tests:**

- 280 pass
- 143 fail

100% of all GET tests **pass**, as well as some POST tests.

However, all tests that **fail** are POST tests. Of these:

- Almost all of them get a 500 Internal Server Error
- They do not log a Response Header or Response Body

So far, I have ensured the app server is listening on the correct ports, and I've restarted the server a few times. Beyond this I'm unsure of how to proceed; most of my experience is in Java desktop applications but I'm now tackling this web application.

**What steps should I try next?**

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error could be almost anything, and in general you would need to look at server/app logs to figure out what happened.  The error could have been thrown because of something unexpected/catastrophic or simply because the server (or rather the programmer/admin) didn't want to expose any more information.

With that said, I would also make sure that your POST request is being sent to an endpoint that is listening/expecting a POST and that the request is properly formatted.